# .ibooks format on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, books

I download a ".ibooks" file for this [free book](http://barabasilab.neu.edu/networksciencebook/downl.html) and tried adding it to my iPhone library but it doesn't show up. Manually dragging it over doesn't work either.

Is it because .ibooks isn't supported by iPhone?

Comment: No .ibooks must be supported by iphone, but why you don't download the book from the book store. If your book is not in the store a iOS device never will show it up.

Comment: Yes. The .ibooks format is not supported by the iPhone, only the iPad. It normally says that right in the Requirements section on every purchase page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done, because only the iPad can read the .ibooks format.  To let Apple know you want this expanded, tell them at

http://www.apple.com/feedback

Answer (score -1):

what you need is .ePub format!

[online Converter](http://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-epub)

Comment: The process you suggest is totally useless for converting the .ibooks format which the OP is asking about to the .epub format.

Comment: why is that? please enlighten me!

Comment: Try it yourself to find out, like you should have done before recommending it as a solution.

Comment: if the questioner wants to add a book, but cant with the current format. and ive added books with epub why should it not work then?

Comment: When the "current format" is .ibooks, it does not work.  Try it for yourself before you recommend it.  If you want to know "why", ask the people who run the site.